# Is there any way to transfer my 500 or so strong Nook library to my new Kindle Paperwhite?

Tags: epub, conversion, drm, mobi

For the time being, let's disregard such niceties as laws and copyright regulations.

I would like to know, basic step by basic step, how to take my nook books and move them to my PC, remove the DRM, transfer from EPUB to MOBI and then, finally, add to my Kindle.

I have read other threads but they left me lost and/or very confused. Something about using my phone?

I'm willing to try almost anything, since my Nook library will cost several thousands to duplicate on my Kindle. Any help is much welcomed and very appreciated.

Comment: Pretty much everything you want to achieve could be done with Calibre and some extra plugins

Comment: My main problem with Calibre is I cannot find the book files. I have no idea where they'd be stored.

Comment: "remove the DRM". You do realize it's illegal under US law for anybody to tell you that, here, right...?  Use the appropriate search tools for your OS to look for .epub files, import those to Calibre (the fastest way to do that, if they're all stored in one directory—and I have no idea if the nook would do that—is to set an "automatic import" directory in Calibre, and copy all your nook files there.